# stacking a line plot on top of a bar plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

My initial bar plot stacks the geohazard number of event per year, on top of which I would like to add a curve line representing the percentage of a certain geohazard per year.

I thought using `ax.twinx()` would work but the curve line in not visible!

```
# Group data by year and count the number of events of each risk type
events_by_year_and_risk = data.groupby(['year', 'hazard'])['decision'].count().unstack()

# Calculate percentage of events that were 'drought'
total_by_year = data.groupby('ann_pub_jo')['decision'].count()
drought_by_year = data[data['hazard'] == 'drought'].groupby('year')['decision'].count()
percentage_by_year = (drought_by_year / total_by_year) * 100

# Create bar plot of events of each risk type per year
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
events_by_year_and_risk.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Events')
ax.set_title('Number of Events by Risk Type and Year')

# Create line plot of percentage of 'drought' events per year
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(percentage_by_year.index, percentage_by_year.values, color='red', marker='o', markersize=3, linewidth=2)
ax2.set_ylabel('Percentage of Drought Events')
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=5)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.0f}%')
ax2.set_ylim(0, 100)

# Adjust layout
fig.tight_layout()

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

When I replace `events_by_year_and_risk.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)`

By `ax1.bar(total_by_year.index, total_by_year.values, color='blue')`

With `total_by_year = data.groupby('year')['decision'].count()`

It doesn't make the graph I want because I want to display the stacked bars. So, there must be something fishy with `stacked`.

Comment: Can you please add a small part of your DataFrame to this post so that we can try to reproduce the error? I just can't get the error without knowing how your data looks is why I ask.

Comment: Maybe you could convert the `year` column to string?  A pandas bar plot always uses a categorical x-axis, while a line plot would use a numeric x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Johanc for your comment. It was indeed an issue between the bar plot and the line plot and it was resolved by converting the indexes in string

```
events_by_year_and_risk.index = events_by_year_and_risk.index.astype(str)
percentage_by_year.index = percentage_by_year.index.astype(str)
```